# Converting from decimal to binary number system using strings

Tags: c, string, binary, decimal

I need help trying to fix the second part of my program, converting decimal to binary, this is what I have so far and when i compile it i keep getting 0 so im not sure what i did wrong. any help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    char string[100];
    int s;
    char a;   
    char j;
    int sum = 0;
    int r;
    int q;

    printf("B = B to D\n");
    printf("D = D to B\n");
    printf("choose which one to convert to:");
    scanf("%c%c", &a, &j);

    if (a == 'B') 
    {
        printf("enter binary number to convert to decimal: ");
        scanf("%s", string);

        for(s = strlen(string)-1; s >= 0; s--)
        {

            if(string[s] == '1')
            {
                sum = sum + pow(2, strlen(string) - (s +1));
            }
        }
        printf("the decimal number is: %d\n", sum);
    }

    if (a == 'D')
    {
        printf("enter decimal number to convert to binary: ");
        scanf("%s", string);

        while (r > 0)
        {
            r = q%2;
            q = q%2;
        } 

        printf("the binary number is: %d\n", r);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `r` before assigning a value to it.

Comment: well its the remainder, but im not sure how to get the string to be divided by 2 in the first place...

Comment: @23ewt3tqa It's not the remainder until you assign it, *inside* the loop. But at that point, the `while` has already tested the value. This is the bug that Musa tried to point out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. For one thing, the first time that you check r, it is uninitialized. Another problem is that you're setting both r and q to the same value every time you go through the while loop. You probably want q = q/2 instead of q = q%2. Finally, you're overwriting r every pass through the loop, instead of building up a string of bits. Here's some pseudocode for what you want to do:

```
 output_string = ""

 while input > 0:
     output_string = concat(input%2, output_string)
     input /= 2

 print output_string
```

Note that you're also never converting the string you read in to an integer and putting that in q, so you'll need to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is probably to convert the string input to a proper integer (using e.g. `strtol`), and the convert that number to a string containing only ones and zeroes.

Something like:

```
/* Convert a (possibly signed) decimal number in a string to a long integer */
unsigned long number = (unsigned long) strtol(string, NULL, 10);

char output_string[65];  /* If longs are 64 bits, plus one for terminator */
char *output_ptr = output_string;

/* Start with the highest bit, go down to the lowest */
/* sizeof(long) is either 4 or 8 depending on 32 or 64 bit platforms */
/* Multiply with 8 to get the number of bits */
/* -1 because bits are numbered from 0 to 31 (or 63) */
for (int bit = (sizeof(unsigned long) * 8) - 1; bit >= 0; bit--)
{
    /* Using right shift to get the current bit into the lowest position */
    /* Doing bitwise AND to see if the lowest bit is a one or a zero */
    /* Adding '0' makes a a printable ASCII value of a digit */
    *output_ptr++ = ((number >> bit) & 1) + '0';

    /* `*output_ptr` gets the value that `output_ptr` points to */
    /* Then use the `++` operator to increase the pointer */
    /* Now `output_ptr` points to the next character in `output_string` */
}

/* Terminate string */
*output_ptr = '\0';

printf("%ld in binary is %s\n", number, output_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

This C99 code will do the trick if you want a negative number to be printed as a string of binary digits with a sign:

```
if (a == 'D')
{
    int r;
    printf("enter decimal number to convert to binary: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    int i = 0;
    int p = (r >= 0) ? (r = -r, 1) : 0;
    string[i++] = '\0';

    do
    {
        string[i++] = (r % 2) == 0 ? '0' : '1';
        r /= 2;
    } while (r != 0);
    if (!p)
        string[i++] = '-';

    int k = 0;
    while (--i > k)
    {
        char t = string[i];
        string[i] = string[k];
        string[k++] = t;
    }

    printf("the binary number is: %s\n", string);
}
```

For example, given `-1234` (decimal), the output is `-10011010010` (binary).  It also handles both the extremes: `INT_MAX`, `-INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` (assuming 32-bit `int`):

```
B = B to D
D = D to B
choose which one to convert to: D
enter decimal number to convert to binary: 2147483647
the binary number is: 1111111111111111111111111111111

B = B to D
D = D to B
choose which one to convert to: D
enter decimal number to convert to binary: -2147483647
the binary number is: -1111111111111111111111111111111

B = B to D
D = D to B
choose which one to convert to: D
enter decimal number to convert to binary: -2147483648
the binary number is: -10000000000000000000000000000000
```

If, on the other hand, you want the bit pattern corresponding to the value, then [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg)'s answer does that for you.

(It's C99 code because it declares variables at convenient points part way through a block, rather than at the start of a block as C89 requires.)